# MySql - SQL - How to avoid duplicate updates in a single query

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok, I have a SQL query that I'm trying to generate that will combine entries based on some logic. I eventually need this to cascade, but I'm running into some issues with things being combined more than I want them to.

Let's see if I can illustrate. I have a table:

```
                             CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS doc_lines (
                              id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                              file_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
                              line int(4) NOT NULL,
                              end_line int(4) NOT NULL,
                              type VARCHAR(100),
                              text VARCHAR( 5120 ) NOT NULL,
                              PRIMARY KEY (id),
                              UNIQUE KEY file_id (file_id,line);
```

```
                          INSERT INTO doc_lines VALUES(1,1,1,1,NULL, 'abcdefg');
                          INSERT INTO doc_lines VALUES(1,1,2,2,NULL, 'hijkl');
                          INSERT INTO doc_lines VALUES(1,1,3,3,NULL, 'mn');
                          INSERT INTO doc_lines VALUES(1,1,4,4,NULL, 'op');
                          INSERT INTO doc_lines VALUES(1,1,5,5,NULL, 'qrs');
                          INSERT INTO doc_lines VALUES(1,1,6,6,NULL, 'tuv.');
                          INSERT INTO doc_lines VALUES(1,1,7,7,NULL, 'wxy');
                          INSERT INTO doc_lines VALUES(1,1,8,8,NULL, 'zab');
```

I'm trying to combine the values of "text" when two lines in a row match a certain condition.

e.g. My existing query is something like the following:

```
  UPDATE doc_lines AS a
  JOIN doc_lines AS b ON a.file_id = b.file_id AND a.end_line + 1 = b.line
  SET a.end_line = b.end_line, b.type="DELETE", a.text=CONCAT(a.text, " ", TRIM(b.text))
  WHERE b.text REGEXP '^[a-z]$';
```

I then follow it up with a:

```
   DELETE from doc_lines WHERE 'type'="DELETE";
```

The problem I'm having is that line 1 matches line 2, which flags line 2 for delete....
Line 2 matches line 3, which flags line 3 for delete...
Line 3 matches line 4, which flags line 4, for delete...
etc

As a result I end up deleting more lines than I want.

At first I thought I could do this to make it skip every other line:

```
  UPDATE doc_lines AS a
  JOIN doc_lines AS b ON a.file_id = b.file_id AND a.end_line + 1 = b.line
  SET a.end_line = b.end_line, b.type="DELETE", a.text=CONCAT(a.text, " ", TRIM(b.text))
  WHERE b.text REGEXP '^[a-z]$' AND a.type <> "DELETE";
```

But the update of one entry in the query doesn't seem to take effect until after the query is done, as a result above doesn't behave any differently...

As a result I thought, "Well, why not handle all the odd lines, then all the even?", so I updated my query appropriately:

```
  UPDATE doc_lines AS a
  JOIN doc_lines AS b ON a.file_id = b.file_id AND a.end_line + 1 = b.line
  SET a.end_line = b.end_line, b.type="DELETE", a.text=CONCAT(a.text, " ", TRIM(b.text))
  WHERE b.text REGEXP '^[a-z]$' AND a.line % 2=0;
```

The problem with this that I need to run the query more than once, because eventually I want lines 1-6 combined and 7-8 (using my example). Each subsequent call combines the lines with the line after it, when it matches.

The problem with this is that eventually I end up hitting the same situation as with my original query and I'm flagging some line for deleting that was also used to flag other lines for deletion.

Even if I end up rotating odd and even on the lines, or the id, or the end_line, at some point there appears to end up being an overlap.

Any ideas? Is there a way to process every-other entry in a database, not based on its actual value?

Comment: Is the goal to concat the text fields of any number of rows that that form a line->end_line->line.. chain? Or just pairwise concatenation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I figured something out that works.

If anyone has anything better, or more efficient... please let me know.

My solution was to create a temporary table which I join to table a:

```
CREATE TABLE update_index SELECT id, @row := @row + 1 as row FROM doc_lines, (SELECT @row := 0) AS r;
```

I can then join to that table, alternate even then delete, then odd then delete, then recreate the temporary table and repeat.

Its a lot of steps, but it works.

I'd definitely be interested in a more elegant or efficient method!